# Wsimport error while parsing WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsimport

I need to consume a SOAP WebService in my application, so I got the WSDL file to generate the needed classes with help of wsimport. The problem is that during parsing I get the following error:

> [ERROR] invalid extension element: "soap:body" (in namespace
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/")

I tried the -extension flag but without success.

Has anyone ran into a similar problem in the past? And if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: Post your WSDL file

Comment: I'm on my phone now, so here is the link http://ws.e-podroznik.pl/?wsdl

Comment: Here's a simpler WSDL that exhibits the same problem: https://gist.github.com/thobbs/4ebd192dacf064d324ad6a05828ced96

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the whole fault...

Trying `wsimport` against that simpler WSDL returned:

```
[ERROR] invalid extension element: "soap:header" (in namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/")
```

The error message doesn't give the location, but the problem is the `<soap:header>` and `<soap:body>` under the parent `<fault>`:

```
<fault name="Error">
    <soap:header message="sm:GetSeatMapCountsErrorOutput" part="header" use="literal"/>
    <soap:header message="sm:GetSeatMapCountsErrorOutput" part="header2" use="literal"/>
    <soap:body parts="body" use="literal" />
</fault>
```

Typically this would be something more like:

```
<fault name="Error">
    <soap:fault name="Error" use="literal" /> 
</fault>
```

It looks like this is correct in the link in the earlier comment (http://ws.e-podroznik.pl/?wsdl).  Perhaps this has been fixed since?

---

To get a clue as to where the invalid `<soap:header>` is in the message, one trick is to use `wsimport -Xdebug`, which will include a stack trace for the exception in the output:

```
Caused by: com.sun.tools.ws.wsdl.framework.ParseException: invalid extension element: "soap:header" (in namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/")
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wsdl.parser.Util.fail(Util.java:186)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wsdl.parser.SOAPExtensionHandler.handleFaultExtension(SOAPExtensionHandler.java:413)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.api.wsdl.TWSDLExtensionHandler.doHandleExtension(TWSDLExtensionHandler.java:87)
```

The clue in there is the `SOAPExtensionHandler.handleFaultExtension()`, which indicates the problem is under the parent `<fault>` element.

Similarly it could have been `handleBindingExtension()` under `<binding>`, `handleOperationExtension()` under `<operation>`, etc.